# How to build array inside private fuction from null?

Tags: java, arrays, function, recursion, multidimensional-array

Im trying to build array inside private function that gets empty array from public function , I call the private function from public and then I try to make the `arr[i][j] = 1` and then the recursion will add to `int j` +1 , but when I do the `arr[i][j] = 1` I get runtime error : NullPointerException,  I don't know the `arr[0].length` , I know only that the `arr.length` is n , any fix ?

```
public static int howManySorted(int n, int max) 
{
     int i = 0;
     int j = 0;
     boolean first = false;
     int count = 0;
     int[][] arr = new int[n][];



     return howManySorted(n,max,arr,i,j,first,count);
}
private static int howManySorted(int n,int max,int[][] arr,int i,int j,boolean first,int count)
{
    if(n < 1)
        return 0;

    if(j < n)
    {
        arr[i][j] = 1;
        count++;
        first = true;
        return howManySorted(n,max,arr,i,j+1,first,count);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

an array that is initialized like this

```
int[][] arr = new int[n][];
```

is not fully initialized and you cannot assign values to cells.
this definition is equal to this: "an array that each cell is defined as an array" so each cell needs to be initialized as well (it doesn't have to be the same size)
you need to either fully initialize the array of arrays like this:

```
int[][] arr = new int[n][n];  // a nxn sized matrix
```

or alternatively, you can initialize each row individually like this:

```
arr[0] = new int[n];  // initialized one cell of arr
```

Comment: Thanks you , I needed the second one of arr[0]

Answer (score 0):

The exception goes away by modifying the code line

```
int[][] arr = new int[n][];
```

to

```
int[][] arr = new int[n][n];
```

When you do `new int[n][]`, it creates an array of `nulls` and doing `arr[i][j]` is like doing `null[j]` which results in the `NullPointerException` 

Alternatively, you could also do,

```
arr[i] = new int[10];  // initialize internal array
```

before doing

```
arr[i][j] = 1 // assign value
```